# Why R is returning object when names are partially matching?

Tags: r, list

Let say I have below `list`

```
Dat = list('AAA' = 1:4, 'BBB' = 5:9)
```

Now I have below syntax

```
Dat$AA
## [1] 1 2 3 4
```

However my question in why `R` is retuning value from `Dat$AA` given that there is no element with such name? Is `R` returning partial names?

If this is the case, then I think such behaviour is utterly risky and should not be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?Extract`

> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

Also, it is written under `name`

> name - A literal character string or a name (possibly backtick quoted). For extraction, this is normally (see under ‘Environments’) partially matched to the names of the object.

where the usage is

> x$name

---

As the `exact` is `FALSE`, it allows for partial matching when we use `$`.  It is one of the reasons to use `[[` where the `exact = TRUE` as the usage is

> x[[i, exact = TRUE]]

It is also mentioned in `?Extract` how to change the `options`

> Thus the default behaviour is to use partial matching only when extracting from recursive objects (except environments) by $. Even in that case, warnings can be switched on by options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE).

Comment: Thank you very much for this very instructive answer.

Comment: Is there any way to stop this behaviour globally?

Comment: You may use `options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

akrun already explained that this behaviour is documented, but generally we prefer that this doesn't happen. Consequently, a set of lines that I always put into my .Rprofile is the following:

```
options(
  warnPartialMatchArgs = TRUE,
  warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE,
  warnPartialMatchAttr = TRUE
)
```

This will be run when R starts, and generate warnings whenever partial matching occurs in R. There are three contexts that it happens as shown: in function arguments, when using `$`, and in using `attr()`. I don't think you can turn the partial matching off entirely, but this should highlight whenever it happens and prevent ensuing bugs.